# How to transform this into passive?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

> She plays with me.

How is this supposed to be passive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She plays with me.

The verb has been used as an intransitive verb in the sentence; there's no object for the verb. So you cannot change the sentence into the passive.

If it's used as a transitive verb i.e. there's an object for the verb play, you can change it into the passive.  For example:

He plays tennis (active voice).

Tennis is played by him (passive voice).

Comment: It's ambiguous if the verb is intransitive or transitive—you're just assuming it's intransitive. It could be meant in the same away as *She toys with me.* In which case, *I am played with by her* would be the passive version.